# Laravel - return controller

Tags: php, html, laravel, controller

My button submit doesn't want to return what i want, it just reload the same page

```
http://projet-site-e-commerce-b2.test/checkout?_token=pFtLTgKao2TfCl450kv8vfpKBcwMqWZtAWjq74l0&_method=POST&email=&name=&address=&city=&country=&postalcode=&phone=&_token=pFtLTgKao2TfCl450kv8vfpKBcwMqWZtAWjq74l0&coupon_code=
```

I'm missing something for sure...

HTML

```
<form action="{{ route('coupon.store') }}" method="POST">
@csrf
    <input type="text" name="coupon_code" id="coupon_code">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Appliquer</button>
</form>
```

Route

```
Route::post('/coupon', 'CouponController@store')->name('coupon.store');
```

CouponController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Coupon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function store(Request $request)
{
 return 'adding coupon';
}
```

Comment: Try returning a redirect

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return redirect('/coupon');
```